# Custom implementation of Bootstrap dropdown in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

I'm trying to build a `Dropdown` component in React with Bootstrap styling without using a library like `react-bootstrap` or `reactstrap`.

I'm a little confused on how to implement the bootstrap javascript into a React component.

I suspect I need to use refs to instantiate a new Dropdown class, but with what I have below the dropdown does nothing and there are no errors in console.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import '@popperjs/core'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js'

import { Dropdown } from 'bootstrap'

function App() {

  const dropdownRef = useRef<any>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (dropdownRef.current) {
      new Dropdown(dropdownRef.current, {
        autoClose:  'inside'
      })
    }
  }, [dropdownRef.current])

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="dropdown">
        <button 
          className="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"              
          type="button" 
          data-bs-toggle="dropdown" 
          aria-expanded="false"
          ref={dropdownRef}
        >
          Dropdown button
        </button>
        <ul className="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark">
          <li><a className="dropdown-item active" href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li><hr className="dropdown-divider" /></li>
          <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

What am I missing here? The [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/dropdowns/) are pretty sparse on how to implement the javascript.

Comment: I know this isn't hugely helpful but what is the reasoning about not using react-bootstrap? Adding it ad-hoc like this is likely to lead to differing representations of the DOM in reacts VDOM and the actual browser DOM, which is not allowed in react apps and will lead to all sorts of nightmares.

Comment: Fundamentally, bootstrap wants you to just mockup the classes and those are the driver of what gets attached where. But in a react app, those are loaded in dynamically after bootstrap hooks in, so it never sees them. That entire approach doesn't work well on a dynamically built SPA and even less so on React because it shouldnt be allowed to interfere with react controlled DOM -- hence why things like react-bootstrap are essentially total rewrites. Can it be forced to work? Probably. Should you? Probably not.

Comment: Not to mention how horrible it would be to map declarative react state to imperative calls. All that said, its probably because you need `useLayoutEffect` and not `useEffect`. The former runs after the DOM is rendered and the ref is populated.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "total rewrite?" I've looked through `react-bootstrap`'s GitHub but don't understand it very well. 
What I can do is capture the dropdown class like `someRef.current = new Dropdown(...)` and use the provided methods of `toggle()`, `show()`, or `hide()`. I would have to manually configure these with options like `autoClose`, though, which I'm trying to avoid. It kinda looks like that's what `reactstrap` did?
I'm doing all this to build my own React/Bootstrap UI components as a practical exercise/portfolio-builder.

Comment: In react-bootstrap, they basically reuse the CSS but it doesnt even call into bootstrap base JS methods. They have essentially "emulated" it, i.e. created a believable duplicate. reactstrap is the same I think as it says "the library does not depend on jQuery or Bootstrap javascript.". Fair enough on the learning approach btw -- though I think this is such a niche thing and a questionable avenue to pursue there could be better use cases to chase up. For your portfolio, id personally be more impressed by something which makes smart choices over the libraries you choose to lean on.

Comment: I had a quick scan and I think the Dropdown class in reactstrap isnt from bootstrap core, its actually part of reactstrap. Also I appreciate this is probably pretty annoying advice im giving , especially if you already invested time. Though I hope is helpful as I reckon you could get more return on investment pursuing other avenues.

Comment: To add just one more datapoint -- I work in a company doing React most days, and our design system is essentially built on top of Chakra, which is an established React design system library. That's seen as something common in a commercial context & so also a desirable action. If looking to demonstrate ability, I reckon you'd be better off wielding open source to its maximum, but focusing on an application that has reasonably complex business logic on top of it. It shows you will make smart choices that maximize ROI, and doesn't need to mean you cant tackle complex challenges.